# Why I receive "Value does not fall within the expected range"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionmailer, mvcmailer

I have an asp.net mvc web application and some external cron job is calling a specific url from my `CronJobController` and execute a specific method like:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Will be called externally by www.setcronjob.com.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        RunTwitterSearchQuery();
        RunFacebookSearchQuery();
        return new ContentResult { Content = "Ok" };
    }
```

in RunTwitterSearchQuery, I want to send some emails and I tried with both [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) and [ActionMailer](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home), for instance (with ActionMailer):

```
var mailController = new MailController();
mailController.HttpContextBase = this.HttpContext;
mailController.MoreThanXFollowersEmail(alertEmailModel).Deliver();
```

Because the http context is null I have to set it in this way to avoid NPE but after that I receive a very strange exception (in both MvcMailer and ActionMailer):

```
    System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
       at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetUserAgentInternal()
       at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetKnownRequestHeader(Int32 index)
       at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_UserAgent()
       at System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_UserAgent()
       at System.Web.WebPages.BrowserHelpers.GetOverriddenUserAgent(HttpContextBase httpContext)
       at System.Web.WebPages.BrowserHelpers.GetOverriddenBrowser(HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 createBrowser)
       at System.Web.WebPages.BrowserHelpers.GetOverriddenBrowser(HttpContextBase httpContext)
       at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.<.ctor>b__2(HttpContextBase context)
       at System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.CanHandleContext(HttpContextBase httpContext)
       at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6.<GetAvailableDisplayModesForContext>b__5(IDisplayMode mode)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
       at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__a(IViewEngine e)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName)
       at ActionMailer.Net.Mvc.EmailResult.LocateViews(ControllerContext context) in c:\Dev\actionmailer\src\ActionMailer.Net.Mvc\EmailResult.cs:line 127
       at ActionMailer.Net.Mvc.EmailResult.AddMessageViews(ControllerContext context) in c:\Dev\actionmailer\src\ActionMailer.Net.Mvc\EmailResult.cs:line 155
       at ActionMailer.Net.Mvc.EmailResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) in c:\Dev\actionmailer\src\ActionMailer.Net.Mvc\EmailResult.cs:line 98
       at ActionMailer.Net.Mvc.MailerBase.Email(String viewName, Object model, String masterName, Boolean trimBody) in c:\Dev\actionmailer\src\ActionMailer.Net.Mvc\MailerBase.cs:line 166
       at SocialCrm.Controllers.MailController.MoreThanXFollowersEmail(AlertEmailModel model) in c:\dev\palminfo\SocialCrm\SocialCrm\Controllers\MailController.cs:line 18
       at SocialCrm.Controllers.CronJobController.SendAlertEmail(SearchResultModel searchResultModel, Int32 searchQueryId, List`1 alerts, String emailTo, String streamName) in c:\dev\palminfo\SocialCrm\SocialCrm\Controllers\Batch\CronJobController.cs:line 146
       at SocialCrm.Controllers.CronJobController.<RunTwitterSearchQuery>b__3() in c:\dev\palminfo\SocialCrm\SocialCrm\Controllers\Batch\CronJobController.cs:line 83
```

This is very ugly and I would really appreciate any help on this issue.

**Update**: when using MvcMailer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19389572/174349) is the error I receive.

Comment: The most obvious thing I can see is make sure `searchQueryId` is a valid Int32, not Int64, string, etc.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, it is, for instance I test with `searchQueryId = 1`. I have a feeling the issue is mostly about httpContext missing some fields when used in this async way...

Comment: Hi @Cristian Boariu, were you able to resolve it? I am experiencing the exact same issue with ActionMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution posted on github for a very similar looking issue if you are using MvcMailer. The solution was to create a new UserMailer every time an email is sent: [Github Answer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/96)

Comment: Tried this too and it does not help.